# Numerical index of characters in byte streams

Tags: java

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class CopyBytes {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    FileInputStream in = null;
    FileOutputStream out = null;

    try {
        in = new FileInputStream("C:\\int.txt");
        out = new FileOutputStream("C:\\out.txt");
        int c;

        while ((c = in.read()) != -1) {
            out.write(c);
        }
    } finally {
        if (in != null) {
            in.close();
        }
        if (out != null) {
            out.close();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Where does the number (-1) come from in this piece of code ?

```
while ((c = in.read()) != -1) {
            out.write(c);.
```

I tried looking on the java tutorials however its only giving me a confusing diagram.

Edit: I changed the value of -1 to -4, this caused the last character to be written many many times. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"`Returns: the next byte of data, or -1 if the end of the file is reached.`" - from http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#read()

Thus, `-1` is used to check when the `EOF` (i.e. end of the file) has been reached and break the loop.

Comment: I know that -1 is returned if the end of the file is reached, however i want to know where did java get that number from,e.g The first word is 0 and the second is 1 etc.

Comment: well, i guess 0 and 1 are used as true/false .. so -1 was chosen by java...i am not sure why -1 and not -2....perhaps best to ask `james gosling` or anyone in the team developing the class. sorry, i dnt know for sure. Also, -1 is a common practice used for socket, so may be -1 was used to be consistent with other similar classes.

Answer (score 2):

The `-1` value marks that the end of the file has been reached and there is nothing more to be read.

[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#read%28%29) is the javadoc for the method.

Answer (score 0):

what in.read() return is a unsigned byte [0,255],if return -1 means that this stream is over,you should not read it anymore. in.read() never return -4.